# Import events into Windows Mobile calendar

Tags: windows-mobile, calendar, calendar.app

I have a .ics file that contains the schedule of a local sports team, how can I use that file to add the dates and times to my Windows mobile phones calendar?

I emailed it to my phone and opened the file, but it only added one event to the calendar.

I don't need constant synchronization with another calendar, I just want to do this one time so I have all the games in my phone.

I don't want to install extra software on my phone.

I don't have Outlook on my PC, I use Thunderbird.

Comment: Are you sure you exported the entire calendar and not just a single event?

Comment: I didn't export it, I downloaded it from the team site.  Opening it with notepad reveals all the events are included, the phone was only adding the first event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Create a GMail account if you don't already have one.
Step 2: Import the .ics file into Google calendar.
Step 3: Follow [These Steps](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138636) to sync the phone with Google.